# Simplest way to split n objects into m sets, where m doesn't divide n?

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer-arithmetic

I have two integers `m` and `n`, with `m < n`. In general, `m` doesn't divide `n`.

Say that `n = m*q + r`, where `q` is the integer quotient of `n` and `m`, and `r` is the remainder (`0 <= r < m`). If we split `n` objects into `m` boxes as homogeneously as possible, `r` of the boxes will contain `q+1` objects and the remaining boxes will contain `q` objects. Suppose that the objects are indexed from `1` to `n`, and that they are inserted into the boxes in order. Moreover, suppose that the first `r` boxes contain `q+1` objects.

I want to write a function that returns a list of indices `i1, i2, ..., im`, such that `i1` is the index of the smallest object in the first box, `i2` the index of the smallest object in the second box, and so on.

I can think of a couple of ways to write this function myself, but I think they are too complicated. I believe there's a simple way to do this that I am not seeing.

Comment: setsize = (n + m  -1) / m; That rounds the setsize up to large enough to hold all elements in smallers sets. Then you take reminder n % m and you know how many first sets are full and rests have one less objects in them.

Comment: @PauliNieminen Yes. But see what I ask. I want to return the list of indices of the smallest objects in each box. And I want a *simple* way to do that, hopefully without many conditionals and loops.

Comment: for (j = 0, i = 0; j < n % m; j++, i+=setsize) ix[j] = i;
for (; j < m; j++, i+=setsize - 1) ix[j] = i;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I did not fully understand what you want to say by 'inserted into the boxes in order', so I'll offer you a solution for the 2 possible meanings.

a) The objects are inserted into the boxes like this:

```
9|
5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4
```

in which case the solution is fairly simple: just print all the numbers from 1 to m.

Code:

```
function foo(int n, int m) {
    for (int k=1; k<=m; k++)
        cout<<k<<endl;
}
```

b)The objects are inserted into the boxes like this:

```
3|6|
2|5|8|10
1|4|7|9
```

in which case, for every box, the object with the smallest index in box k is: (n / m) * (k - 1) + min(k, n % m + 1)

Code:

```
function foo(int n, int m) {
    for (int k=1; k<=m; k++)
        cout<<(n / m) * (k - 1) + min(k, n % m + 1)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `q` objects to every box. If the box is one of the `n - m*q == n % m` first ones, add one extra object:

```
std::vector<int> starts_of(int n, int m)
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    int q = n / m;
    int s = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        v.push_back(s);
        s += q;
        if (i < n % m) s++;
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Your inded starts at 0.  Question says 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = n % m
d = n / m
//with two loops without conditionals:
for i = 0..r - 1
   I[i] = 1 + i * d  + i    
for i = r..m - 1
   I[i] = 1 + i * d + r
//or with single loop:
for i = 0..m - 1
   I[i] = 1 + i * d  + min(i, r)
```

Comment: what language is that? Is that C++?

Comment: It is pseudocode. `for i = 0..r - 1` is equal to `for(int i=0; i<r; i++)`

Comment: You might as well write in C++.

Comment: I could make silly errors in C++ code and don't sure what C++ collection data structure is suitable.